# Base Admin class with a dynamic list_display

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-admin

I have written a base class for admin classes for all of my classes that have a field called `is_active`. It enables the user to see the records of the table along with the `is_active` field so that they can see which record is active or not and they can edit it.

For most of the classes that I have in my models, there is a field called `name` so I can easily write 2 lines of the code in `admin.py` and have a customized admin representation, but the problem is for the classes that don't have a field called `name` so I have to use a different field in `list_display` . Since the number of these classes is high, I am looking for a solution to either dynamically get the name of the field that must be in the `list_display`. Any ideas to solve this problem would be much appreciated.

**models.py:**

```
class BaseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     list_display=('id','name','is_active')
     list_editable = ('is_active',) # this MUST only contain fields that also are in "list_display"
     search_fields=('name',)


class ClassA(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, unique=True,)
    is_active=models.BooleanField(default=True,)

    def __str__(self):
            return self.name

class ClassB(models.Model):
    my_field=models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, unique=True,)
    is_active=models.BooleanField(default=True,)

    def __str__(self):
            return self.my_field
```

**admin.py**

```
class ClassAAdmin(BaseAdmin):
   pass

class ClassBAdmin(BaseAdmin):
   pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `get_list_display` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_list_display

Use that in conjunction with `ModelAdmin.model` (i.e. `self.model` inside the `get_list_display` method) to create a dynamic list display based on the model.

Note that I would personally recommend not baking this automation into the `BaseAdmin`, and defining what is different between the subclass `ModelAdmin`s (in this case, `list_display`) separately.  It's more explicit and clear. This is pure opinion though.

Comment: I knew about `get_list_display` but my problem is that I could not figure out how. If it was 10-20 classes, I would not mind defining them separately, but we are talking about 100-200 ones so it is quite worth it to come up with something a lot shorter. I cannot figure out how I can give the method a list of all fields (one field for each class) so it can choose the right one for the list_display